# Update sub array of object in a store

Tags: svelte, svelte-store

I use a store in which I store an array containing objects. These objects also contain an array (Messages) that is used to display checkboxes. I would like, when I click on a "Select All" button, that all checkboxes of the selected item are selected and that this is reflected in the UI. I can change the attribute of my object to indicate that it is checked but the UI does not update.

Here is what I wrote:

```
<script>
let selectedIndex = 0;
const messages = writable([]);
data :
[
    {
        Id: 1,
        Messages: [
            {
                Id: 1,
                Name: 'Message 1_1',
                IsEnabled: false,
                IsSelected: true
            },
            {
                Id: 2,
                Name: 'Message 1_2',
                IsEnabled: true,
                IsSelected: false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        Id: 2,
        Messages: [
            {
                Id: 1,
                Name: 'Message 2_1',
                IsEnabled: false,
                IsSelected: true
            },
            {
                Id: 2,
                Name: 'Message 2_2',
                IsEnabled: true,
                IsSelected: false
            },
            {
                Id: 3,
                Name: 'Message 2_3',
                IsEnabled: true,
                IsSelected: true
            }
        ]
    }
]
messages.set(data);

function selectAll() {
    messages.update(items => 
        {
            for (let index = 0; index < items[selectedIndex].Messages.length; index++) {
                items[selectedIndex].Messages[index].IsSelected = true;
            }
            return items;
        });
}
</script>


<ul>
{#each $messages[selectedIndex].Messages as item}
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" width="16" height="16" bind:checked="{$messages[selectedIndex].Messages[i].IsEnabled}" on:change="{() => manageChange($messagesByStructures[selectedIndex].Messages[i].Id)}">
        <label>{item.Id}</label>
    </li>
{/each}
</ul>

<button class="button-base" on:click="{() => selectAll()}">Select All</button>
```

How do I reflect the change in the UI of a sub array of an object? Do I have to make a copy of the original array and then make a new assignment? Is it the only way?

```
copyOfArray = [...$data]
messages.set(copyOfArray);
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`selectAll` modifies `IsSelected` but the `checked` binding is to `IsEnabled`

```
bind:checked="{$messages[selectedIndex].Messages[i].IsEnabled}"
```

Inside a component there's [the `$` prefix](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-4-prefix-stores-with-$-to-access-their-values) for stores to access and modify their value. When using this, [assignments are important](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-2-assignments-are-reactive) and `selectAll` could also look like this

```
function selectAll() {
        $messages[selectedIndex].Messages.forEach(message => message.IsSelected = true)
        $messages = $messages
    }
```

(It is unusual to start the object keys with a capital letter)

Comment: Thank you Corrl for your answer. Yes, sorry for the IsSelected and IsEnabled. I rewrote a "simple" data object for the question and forgot to check that everything matched... I will be more careful next time. For the capital letters, it's because I send this data to an API written in C# that PascalCase. For me it's easier to have the object keys like that but maybe I'm wrong on the C# side. Again, thank you for your answer.